# How do I bind google visualization category filter with all filters at any direction of selection?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have three category filter which had a binding clockwise direction of dropdown selection. Now I need to bind it for any direction. It means, If I select any dropdown other 2 dropdown should be filter their values.

**Code works for clockwise direction:**

```
    var cblAnalyst = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper(
    {
        'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
        'containerId': 'cblAnalyst',
        'options': {
            'filterColumnIndex': '0', 'ui': {
                'label': '', 'labelSeparator': ':', 'labelStacking': 'horizontal', 'allowTyping': false, 'allowNone': true, 'allowMultiple': false
            }
        }
    });

    var cblAdvocate = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper(
    {
        'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
        'containerId': 'cblAdvocate',
        'options': {
            'filterColumnIndex': '1',
            'ui': { 'label': '', 'labelSeparator': ':', 'labelStacking': 'horizontal', 'allowTyping': false, 'allowNone': true, 'allowMultiple': false }
        }
    });

    var cblProductNames = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper(
    {
        'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
        'containerId': 'cblProductNames',
        'options': {
            'filterColumnIndex': '7',
            'ui': { 'label': '', 'labelSeparator': ':', 'labelStacking': 'horizontal', 'allowTyping': false, 'allowNone': true, 'allowMultiple': false }
        }
    });

    var tblSearchFilters = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'Table',
        'containerId': 'tblSearchFilters',
        'options': {
            'allowHtml': true, 'showRowNumber': true, 'page': 'enable', 'pageSize': 10,
            width: '100%'
        }
    });

    new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'))
        .bind(cblAnalyst, cblAdvocate)
        .bind(cblAdvocate, cblProductNames)
        .bind(cblProductNames, tblSearchFilters)
        .draw(dtSearchFilters);
```

**Category filter drawn:**

[image]

**Solution looking for:**

I should be able to filter the Analyst and Advocate when i chosen the product.

**EDITED:**

**Sample Data:**

```
Filter 1    Filter 2    Filter 3 (Apply filter here)
AN - 1  AD - 1  PD - 1
AN - 1  AD - 1  PD - 2
AN - 1  AD - 2  PD - 3
AN - 2  AD - 3  PD - 4
AN - 2  AD - 4  PD - 5
```

Copy this into excel spreadsheet and apply filter as specified..

Answer (score 1):

the question is difficult to understand without a working example

typically, when binding multiple controls to the same chart(s),
only one `bind` call is needed

```
new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'))
    .bind([cblAnalyst, cblAdvocate, cblProductNames], tblSearchFilters)
    .draw(dtSearchFilters);
```

this will keep all the filters in sync with the table

for instance, if a *Product* is selected,
only the remaining *Analysts* and *Advocates* associated with that product will be available in the filters

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. I tried it. But no Luck. Though I select product, I am able to see other options also in the remaining filters.

Comment: It is more are like excel filter functionality. I can filter by any columns in the spreadsheet and similar case applies here. Filter by product should filter other two and should repeat the same functionality for other filters also.

Comment: simply don't follow, will you share a sample of the data?